# How to reference a string of text then hyperlink it to a url?

Tags: url, hyperlink

My problem is i need a bit of code to reference a tracking number eg 1193849302, and insert it into a url http://www.example.com/track=[tracking number], so that the [tracking number] is replaced by 1193849302

then to have showing only the tracking number which is hyperlinked to said URL, i.e. 1193849302 (hyperlinked)

Either in html or javascript I think most of the site is CSS based though

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Edit maybe i should explain what i want a bit better

I have a customer area on a retail website , which returns the customers parcels tracking number when despatched.

What i'm after is a way to turn this tracking number into a working hyperlink which when clicked opens a new window into the couriers website automatically pushing the tracking number into the url and tracking the parcel for them.

Does this sound possible??

Comment: are you writing in php, html, asp .net?

Comment: Could you please show your " bit of code to reference a tracking number eg 1193849302"?

Comment: That what i need!!! the bit of code

Comment: *"which returns the customers parcels tracking number"* - How is it returned? In a hidden input field after a HTTP request? After an AJAX call? And what do you want to do with this nummer? Insert the link in the HTML document? Send it to another webservice? It is unclear what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have a `String.replace` function.

For example, in Javascript, use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for this. Note that it takes a regex as an argument, so the `[]` need to be escaped:

```
var str = "http://www.example.com/track=[tracking number]";
str = str.replace("\[tracking number\]", "1193849302");
```

Comment: But then how can i convert the tracking number into a hyperlink reference using this so that the only thing showing in the window?

Answer (score 0):

use String.replace method 
The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

```
var str="http://www.example.com/track=[tracking number]";
var n=str.replace("tracking number","1193849302");
```

You can find more informations at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp